# Extracting point data from WMS using R. Is it possible?

Tags: r, wms

I am collecting traffic accident data on European countries and the Austrians pointed me to this WMS metadata page.

https://data.statistik.gv.at/web/meta.jsp?dataset=OGDEXT_UNFALLSRV_1

which has the link

https://www.statistik.at/gs-open/ATLAS_UNFALL_OPEN/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

Is is possible to retrieve the underlying point data using R? I'm not interested in displaying it on a map (but I can't even figure out how to do that).

I'm interested in the layers unfall_koord_2017 - unfall_koord_2020.

Comment: You need to look for a wfs endpoint to get the actual data.

Comment: Thanks, I looked around the website (link above) and through the getcapabilities xml file and didn't find anything obvious that pointed me to a wfs endpoint. My plan is to contact the data maintainer, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious or through ignorance of the wms format.

Comment: an example https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/44c29e112a2eccbe4a9f96840ec1f151

Comment: Note @mdsumner's code shows how to get the raster so you can map it - don't get your hopes up that it'll get you the point data!

Comment: Attempts to access a possible WFS endpoint at https://www.statistik.at/gs-open/ATLAS_UNFALL_OPEN/wfs get "Service WFS is disabled" in QGIS. :(

Comment: oh right, yes *the data* not the image data ... lol

Comment: So I can accept an answer, could one of you please synthesize these responses? I think for future users with my same question, it would be good to know how to find the WFS endpoint if you know the WMS endpoint. Also, some people may just need raster data and not point, so a link to that example could be good, but also clarify that point data is not obtainable. Thanks again!